# How do I Submit througt a Dynamic dropdown list in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

MVC web application on AspNetCore6

I have deasign a Database with some simple elemement called "receipts" containing parameter that I can Delete, Edit ect (I used scaffolding).
My goal now is to be able to select one of the "receipts" and apply it. then i could pass a message in the controller that specify clearly that this specific recipe as been selected in this web site.

It might be wierd speaking of receipt without context. But this recipe when applied will change some external parameter from real life systeme element with tcp udp request. Anyway its not important here. Just explain if you want more context.

**Do you know how to do that task ?**

[image: Here is a picture of my view.](y I am french ...)

**View**

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Recette séléctionnée
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Recette){
                    <li>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("RecetteSlct", "Recettes"))
                        {
                            <button type="submit" name="item"  class="dropdown-item" value="1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</button>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
{
public class RecettesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RecetteSlct()
    {
        //here retrieve the item id that as been selected and then its gonna do some back end stuff, but the backend stuff is not requested here.
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
    public class Recette
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Nom")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Do not hesitate to ask thing if they are not explain or details enougth !

Comment: pass the value into your method: `public ActionResult RecetteSlct(int item)` where the name of the variable should match the name of the button (or you can make a model with that property on it and pass that into the method)

Comment: Ok but then how do i specify the value in my method ? I mean , here i would write "int item" but in fact i would pass an item with a value of 0.  

The question is then:  in the View, How do I inject the value the RecipeID into my item. Some code example would be really helpfull.

Comment: `value="@item.RecipeID"`?  Perhaps you should read the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Well my bad it worked in fact i thought my id should be more complexe (used to because of my registration code before) and the fact that it return 1 is completly normal. Thanks Pete !